# Can I schedule a Package to run via Oracle scheduled Jobs

Tags: oracle, plsql, job-scheduling, oracle12c

I have created a Package within Oracle SQL Developer. I am trying to run this package as a scheduled job within Oracle. I am unable to run a package using the job scheduler. I am able to run stored procedures via the job scheduler. My research has turned up no results - the only information i find is how to use the Job Scheduler Package, which is not my issue. Does anyone have experience with scheduling a package....is it possible via Oracle?  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'run a package' - a package is not executable, you'd need to run a procedure inside the package. Please add what you're trying to run, and what errors you get when you try,

Comment: I would like to add one more comment apart from @AlexPoole comment which is procedure must be a able to access from outside, i,e, procedure must have public access.

Comment: the package consists of 6 procedures within the package body:

Comment: Package Name: School_export Package body: School_export_pkg_body. Body contains 6 procedures: Export Students, Sync student data, sync custom student data, log_open, log_close and log_line. in addition there are three items contained in the package that reside outside the package body: school_map,type, handle and school_map. I am able to execute package within oracle dev by right clicking and then running. When I try to execute via a scheduled job ... the job attempts to start and immediately shuts down. Should I be scheduling the job to execute the Package body rather than the package itself?

Comment: I still don't quite know what you mean; 'running' the package in SQL Developer sounds like you're compiling it, not executing/calling a procedure within it. You still haven't said exactly what you're calling from your job. Why not show that code? In your last comment the package spec and body seem to have different names, which doesn't make sense either.

Comment: I couldn't include the code for the package body as it contains 385 lines. The package is :create or replace PACKAGE SCHOOL_EXPORT_PKG AS PROCEDURE LOG_OPEN;
PROCEDURE LOG_CLOSE; PROCEDURE LOG_LINE(line VARCHAR2); PROCEDURE EXPORT_STUDENTS;
PROCEDURE SYNC_ALL_STUDENT_DATA(PROCESS_ALL_IN INTEGER);
PROCEDURE SYNC_CUSTOM_STUDENT_DATA(STUDENT_NUMBER_IN VARCHAR2);
TYPE school_map_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
school_map school_map_type;
END SCHOOL_EXPORT_PKG;

Comment: The code above is for the package - the package body contains the code for each procedure listed. When I right click and select run on the Package the package runs through all of the procedures (PROCEDURE LOG_OPEN;
PROCEDURE LOG_CLOSE;
PROCEDURE LOG_LINE
PROCEDURE EXPORT_STUDENTS;
PROCEDURE SYNC_ALL_STUDENT_DATA,
PROCEDURE SYNC_CUSTOM_STUDENT_DATA )contained in the package body.  This does execute the procedures contained in the package - the package has already been compiled

Comment: Please *edit the question* to include the code you are using to create and run your *job*.

Comment: sorry - I misread - i'll send the job code

Comment: 1. When you say you run, do you mean you are executing "DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB" to create the job? 
2. What is the output when you run immediately using "dbms_scheduler.run_job"?
3. Have you checked user_scheduler_jobs and user_scheduler_job_logs for the status/error info?

Answer (score 0):

Set the parameters job_type to `'PLSQL_BLOCK'` and job_action to `'begin mypackage.myproc(myparams); end;'`. Do not forget to duplicate apostrophes when used inside the string. (The string is the same as by `execute immediate`.)

Comment: Thanks so much for responding to my question Alex and Pavel.  Pavel - your answer was spot on!!! I ran a few tests to double check my work before declaring it a success.  Thanks a million!!!